# Can't call forAll on int[]

Tags: c#

I'm reading `Effective C# by Bill Wagner` regarding query syntax and there is this example:

```
int[] foo = (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                     select n * n).ToArray();
foo.ForAll((n) => Console.WriteLine(n.ToString()));
```

when testing it I get this error:

> 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'ForAll' and no extension method 'ForAll' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I used the following directives:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

what else am I missing?
thanks in advance

update: testing on VS 2012 & .Net 4.5

both [w.b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703033/559465) and [Ned Stoyanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702993/559465) answers work but not the example as it's in the book.
should I consider that just a wrong example?

I just noticed that `AsParallel` doesn't produce the expected result from the example.
Mentally running the example code it should print numbers from 0 to 99*99 in ascending order, while `AsParallel` prints the numbers but not the same order. So I guess `AsParallel` is not the exact answer, no?

Comment: There is a `ForEach` extension on a `List<T>` interface, there is no `ForAll`

Comment: Which framework version are you using?

Comment: Ok then, as someone said, forall comes with PLINQ. You can use that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You omitted some important text from between those two lines of code, and immediately after them.

Excerpted from *"Effective C# (Covers C# 4.0): 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your C#"* by Bill Wagner:

> ```
> int[] foo = (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
>             select n * n).ToArray();
> ```
>
> You can then do a similar change to the second loop, although you'll also need to write an extension method to perform some action on all the elements:
>
> ```
> foo.ForAll((n) => Console.WriteLine(n.ToString()));
> ```
>
> The .NET BCL has a ForAll implementation in List<T>. It's juts as simple to create one for IEnumerable<T>:
>
> ```
> public static class Extensions
> {
>     public static void ForAll<T>(
>         this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
>         Action<T> action)
>     {
>         foreach (T item in sequence)
>             action(item);
>     }
> }
> ```

He created a `ForAll` extension method himself, so you'll need to copy that code too for your program to compile. It's just an extension method that uses `foreach` to loop over the elements in `foo` and perform the `Console.WriteLine()` action on each of them.

Comment: This is the right answer. [You can have a look](https://github.com/BillWagner/PracticalLINQ/blob/master/PracticalLINQ/PracticalLINQ/LinqUtillities.cs) at the LinqUtilities class from the author's github

Comment: My bad :) I guess I should improve my reading concentration before my C#! thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `ForAll` in PLINQ, in which case your code should be:

```
foo.AsParallel().ForAll((n) => Console.WriteLine(n.ToString()));
```

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd383744%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the documentation. *Note that `AsParallel` invokes the specified action for each entry in parallel and therefore not execute the lambda for each entry in the order of the entries in the enumerable.*

Comment: thanks I'm sure that's a way around the issue. I'm just trying to understand the example as it's in the book ^_^

Comment: I just noticed that `AsParallel` doesn't produce the expected result from the example. Mentally running the example code it should print numbers from 0 to 99*99 in ascending order, while `AsParallel` prints the numbers but not the same order

Comment: yes it executes them concurrently, I should have pointed that out

Answer (score 1):

Change your data structure to `List<int>` and call `ForEach` on it:

```
List<int> foo = (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                     select n * n).ToList();
foo.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n.ToString()));
```

Comment: thanks I'm sure that's a way around the issue. I'm just trying to understand the example as it's in the book ^_^